# Open Source Video Conferencing Server

Tags: asterisk, conference

How to create a Open Source Video Conferencing Server using Asterisk? Is it possible? I would like to create a n-way conference call but I cant using MeetMe and zaptel. I don't have Digium hardware. I am using asterisk 1.8 on ubuntu 10.10.

Need some advices. How to do this?

APpreciate!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asterisk  able do only following video conference: one person speaking, all other see that person.

To create that use ConfBridge or Meetmee, but ensure before that u have video call between ALL party and all have SAME video codec and SAME video size/bitrate.

Asterisk not support mixing or change of videostream. See vmuktu and BigBlueButton for examples of video conferences.

Comment: i am using MeetMe, but I only hear audio, no video. How to configure asterisk for video calls?

Comment: You have to check video with usual call.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is alternative and the better one! you should try [ConfBridge](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ConfBridge) even ConfBridge was introduced since Asterisk 1.6.2 but as per your video requirement I suggest you to upgrade Asterisk version to Asterisk 10 [see here for new features](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge+10)

Comment: can you give me some examples with MeetMe. I've done a test but there is no video. In extensions.conf I've written exten => 1234,Meetme(1234); where 1234 is the conf room. There is no video. Why?

Comment: 1.10 is VERY buggy now. use 1.6-1.8

Comment: So, first of all, its Asterisk 10, not 1.10.  As far as "very buggy", I'm not sure what you're referring to.  There have been a few issues reported against the video capabilities in ConfBridge, but those have been resolved as of 10.2.0.  If you have a problem with video support in ConfBridge, then I highly recommend you report it on the Asterisk issue tracker.